# Angular website not displaying dates in correct format

Tags: angular, angular-material

We have an angular web site where we display dates on certain pages.
The way we display the dates is like this:

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
  {{ niceDate(row.openedOnUtc) }}
</td>
```

When building the app locally, everything is fine. However, when deployed onto Azure we see the following.
This first image is what dates are shown as when we browse to the page. All other content displays correctly and all data is coming from the same backend API call.

[image]
If we now click on a different tab in our app and then go back, then we can see the dates displayed correctly.

[image]
This is reproducible on different browsers.
Checking the dev tools there are no errors shown when the dates don't display correctly, so we're a bit confused as to what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, `nicedate()` was an internal function that seems to have had issues turning the date into a localised format.
We changed it now into a generalised format and that works.

Instead of `return dayjs(isoDate).format('lll');` we're now calling `return dayjs(isoDate).format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm');` in the `nicedate()` function.